# JPA NamedQuery parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Is there any convention how to name parameters in `JPQL`?Because today after some debugging I realized that I can't put inside name for example colon.

Also I discovered second problem, from some reason I can't use use constants as parameter names. I will always get a

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:466)
```

Here is my code

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name=Lookup.GET_LOOKUP_DATA_QUERY, 
        query="SELECT t.textShort, lookup.metaCode, lookup.tableName FROM Lookup lookup, Txt t" +
                " WHERE (lookup.metaCode = t.txtHeadCode OR t.txtHeadCode IS NULL) AND lookup.module.id =:" + Lookup.PARAM_MODULE_ID +
                " AND lookup.metaCode IN (:" + Lookup.PARAM_LOOKUP_META_CODES + ") AND t.lang.metaCode = 'lang_cz'")
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE")
public class Lookup {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final String GET_LOOKUP_DATA_QUERY = "Lookup.GetLookupDataQuery";
public static final String PARAM_MODULE_ID = "Lookup.PARAM_MODULE_ID";
public static final String PARAM_LOOKUP_META_CODES = "Lookup.PARAM_LOOKUP_META_CODES";

@Id
@Column(name ="META_CODE")
private String metaCode;

@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="MODULE_ID")
private Module module;
}
```

+ getters, setters and other properties

Provider is `Hibernate` but query is written in pure `JPA`

So does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use characters that are not part of valid identifier as defined by [Character.isJavaIdentifierPart](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart%28char%29).  named parameters are defined in JPA 2.0 specification:

> A named parameter of a Java Persistence query language query is an
>   identifier that is prefixed by the ":" symbol. The parameter names
>   passed to the setParameter methods of the Query and TypedQuery
>   interfaces do not include this ":" prefix.
>   ...
>   An identifier is a character sequence of unlimited length. The
>   character sequence must begin with a Java identifier start character,
>   and all other characters must be Java identifier part characters. An
>   identifier start character is any character for which the method
>   Character.isJavaIdentifierStart returns true. This includes the
>   underscore (_) character and the dollar sign ($) character. An
>   identifier part character is any character for which the method
>   Character.isJavaIdentifierPart returns true. The question mark (?)
>   character is reserved for use by the Java Persistence query language.

Using constants when query string for @NamedQuery is built does not cause problems. It is compile time construct and Hibernate is not aware of was this query built with constants or not.

In your current query all named parameters are invalid. That is because of '.'. According Character.isJavaIdentifierPart it is not one of the valid characters.

Comment: I updated my post (I put there original constants values which were causing me the problems). In this configuration I am not able to build the query and I am getting the exception as above. According to spec the underscore shoudn't cause the problems, but in my case, when I remove the underscore, problem disappers, so it's really strange

Comment: Underscore should not cause problem. If it does, then it violates specification.  All parameter names you use are invalid because of '.'. As specified by Character.isJavaIdentifierPart, it is not valid.